# Gradle build incredibly slow

Tags: android, performance, gradle

Build time right now is ranging around ~2-4 min.

I'm using about 11 libraries provided via Gradle.

I have the following set:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        multiDexEnabled = true
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4096M"
    preDexLibraries false
    jumboMode = true
    incremental = true
}
```

Gradle: `Offline mode`

I have the following setting in gradle.properties
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

In the global properties I have:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

I've looked through about every article I can find on it on Google/Stackoverflow.

Is there any way to speed the process up to below 1 minute at least?

**Update August 6, 2015**

These really helped speed things up for me.

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

**build.gradle** project dependencies

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

**Update August 9, 2015**

I've found that as it turns out using [Protoc](https://github.com/google/protobuf) is very very slow for Android.  I switched to [Wire](https://github.com/square/wire) and it took the compilation time from 2 min. to 10s-30s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `multiDexEnabled = true` makes my build process extremely slow. I don't know if it's possible to improve it's performance somehow, but for now I just turned it off.

You have to use it only if amount of methods in your project (including libraries) goes beyond 65k limit. Maybe you can cut off some of your 11 libraries, then turning off `multiDexEnabled` option should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also upgrade gradle by editing the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and set gradle-2.4-all.zip

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `gradle daemon`.

Create a file named `gradle.properties` in the following directory:

- /home//.gradle/ (Linux)
- /Users//.gradle/ (Mac)
- C:\Users\.gradle (Windows)

Add this line to the file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

From now on Gradle will use a daemon to build, whether you are using Gradle from command line or building in Android Studio.